# Injury VS Injuries in this context

Tags: differences, vocabulary

I came across this exercise in the Cambridge English Advanced exam:
[image]

> Because he was injured he couldn't play in the next game.
>
> PREVENTED
>
> His ______________________ in the next game.
>
> ANSWER: injury prevented him from playing

Would "injuries" instead of "injury" work? As far as I'm concerned this exam only accepts the most idiomatic answer, but is this really the case if "injuries" would be more standard according to Google Ngram View?
[image]

Comment: Please take the time to type out the words in the image, since that is absolutely fundamental to the question. Images are unsearchable and inaccessible to screen-readers (except via the title, which which must be short and which you haven't set anyway).

Comment: _Injuries_ would be 'changing the word given', which they tell you not to do. There is no reason to prefer the plural unless it's known that the person had suffered multiple injuries.

Comment: @KateBunting no, the word given is "PREVENTED".

Comment: OK - but that doesn't change the fact that the plural is not 'more standard', it merely depends on what had happened to the victim. This sentence presumably refers to a sportsman, so a single injury is more likely.

Comment: @KateBunting That actually answers my question, thanks! I guess I wanted to check with a native speaker if "injuries" could be used if it's a single injury.

Comment: Your test question says *injured*, so it does not care that the plural is common or not. The anal quality of these tests cannot be overstated.

Comment: *but is this really the case if "injuries" would be more standard according to Google Ngram View?* Yes, **of course** it is valid - you will note that *both* are used. If you look at some contextual examples, you may see why the singular or plural has been used. (Your image is a misuse of Google Ngrams - language is not a democratic process in which the most frequently appearing word is always used.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original sentence doesn't say whether he received one injury or multiple injuries, so either answer could be correct.  Of course, it's more likely that he received only a single injury, which is probably why the test expects "injury" rather than "injuries." But the real answer is that the question is poorly written.